# Will this hardware be 64bit Windows Server 2008 compatible?

Tags: hardware, windows-server-2008

I recently printed out Jeff Atwood's [Understanding The Hardware](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001157.html) blog post and plan on taking it to Fry's Electronics and saying to them "Give me all the parts on these sheets so I can put this together." However, I'm going to be installing 64bit Windows Server 2008 on this machine so before I get all the parts:

Will all this hardware be 64bit Server 2008 compatible? - i.e. all drivers available for this hardware for this OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardware's generally pretty OS-agnostic (at least in terms of Windows flavors) these days. Your only concern is getting drivers for other devices (scanners, printers, IR remotes) that won't work on 64bit and/or won't work on "Server" OSes. Online backup software like Mozy generally won't even install on a Server OS, so it depends on what you're going to use it for.

That said, if you're just going to use it for a home machine, then without even looking at the hardware list Jeff put together, I'd be confident in saying it'll probably work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all that stuff should be fine (motherboard and CPU hardware, motherboard drivers, video card drivers).

Answer (score -2):

You have a $1000 operating system license and you're going to put it on ~$1100 worth of hardware purchased at Fry's and presumably put together by yourself?